# Curl to test the method

Tags: spring-mvc

With reference to this tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param
I am trying to test this method

```
@PostMapping("/api/foos")
@ResponseBody
public String addFoo(@RequestParam(name = "id") String fooId, @RequestParam String name) { 
    return "ID: " + fooId + " Name: " + name;
}
```

Can anyone please suggest me the curl command so that I can get back both id and name in string format .

Answer (score 1):

Try below.

`$ curl -d "id=1&name=abc" http://localhost:8080/api/foos`/

Refer [this thread](https://superuser.com/a/149335/921518)